# Error: cars is not defined angular.js:12477:18

Tags: angularjs

Делаю первое приложение на Angular. Запнулся на получении данных из json для вывода на шаблон. Проблема: при переходе на страницу *cars* вижу ошибку:

> Error: cars is not defined angular.js:12477:18

Вот код ниже, буду благодарен за помощь

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/home">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/login">login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/profile">profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/cars">cars</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <!-- <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">-->upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="views/profile.js"></script>
  <script src="views/cars.js"></script>
  <script src="views/home.js"></script>
  <script src="views/login.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**cars.html**

```
<h1>Cars Page</h1>

<ul class="cars">
  <li ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <div class="car">
      <div href="cars/{{car.id}}" class="carView">
        <img ng-src="{{car.image}}" alt="{{car.name}}"/>
        <p>{{car.title}}</p>
        <p>{{car.color}}</p>
        <p>{{car.description}}</p>
      </div>
      <button class="addBtn">Add car</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**cars.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.cars', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/cars', {
    templateUrl: 'views/cars.html',
    controller: 'carsCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('carsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get(cars.json)
      .success(function($scope,data){
        console.log("This is data: ", data, "\n This is Status: ", status, "\n This is Headers: ", headers, "\n This is config: ", config);
        $scope.cars = data;
      })
      .error(function(){
        alert("can not get data from cars.json")
      });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как запрос отрабатывает асинхронно, то при построения вьюхи, приложение может не знать, что такое `cars`.

Нужно просто объявить свойство `cars` в контроллере:

```
.controller('carsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.cars = {};
  $http.get(cars.json)
      .success(function(data){
        console.log("This is data: ", data, "\n This is Status: ", status, "\n This is Headers: ", headers, "\n This is config: ", config);
        $scope.cars = data;
      })
      .error(function(){
        alert("can not get data from cars.json")
      });
}]);
```

**UPD1**
Невнимательность, сори...

> Нужно так же убрать `$scope` из `$http.get(cars.json).success(function(data){});`

Comment: Добавил. не спасло. та же ошибка

Comment: Заголовок от вьюхи `Cars Page` отображается?

Comment: да, <h1>Cars Page</h1> отображается. при переходе на cars вижу Cars Page

Comment: Выложите код на `jsfiddle` или подобном, что бы можно было поиграться.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/wrath1888/v80rcLz8/ здесь получше работает, чем локально

Comment: Здесь вообще не работает! Исправьте все текущие ошибки, что в консоле. Файлы не относящиеся к вопросу, можно исключить, оставьте только проблемную часть. Файл `cars.json` можно загрузить на сторонний ресурс или сделайте обращение вообще к произвольному ресурсу, дабы эмулировать запрос, а в ответе уже, но только ручками, присвойте нужный массив. Можно не весть 2-3 машины.

Comment: заменил $http.get(cars.json) на $http.get('views/cars.json'). Теперь ошибки в консоли нет, но на странице Cars Page только хедер Cars Page

Comment: Скиньте новую ссылку, по старой (jsfiddle.net/wrath1888/v80rcLz8/) старый код.

Comment: Закинул на codenvy https://codenvy.com/ide-resources/share/project/wrath1888/untitled1

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29906/discussion-on-answer-by-borodatych-error-cars-is-not-defined-angular-js124771).

Comment: Я считаю, все же не стоит. ТС, обновил ответ. Теперь должно быть все гуд! Успехов в начинание!))

Comment: @borodatych, отлично! спасибо огромное! работает! 
$http.get('views/cars.json')
            .success(function(data){$scope.cars = data;})